# Appcelerator Titanium custom design Map View

Tags: javascript, titanium, mkmapview, appcelerator

I need to use google maps in my app, i have tried following code to achieve my design but no luck.

Here is my code,

```
var anno = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
        title : "150$",
        subtitle : "Its sub title",
        latitude : 37.390749,
        longitude : -122.081651,
        title : "Appcelerator Headquarters",
        subtitle : 'Mountain View, CA',
        pincolor : Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
        image : "/images/MapPin.png",
        animate : true,
        leftButton : '/images/MapPin.png',
        myid : 1
    });

    var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    borderColor : "red",
    mapType : Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region : {
    latitude : 37.390749,
    longitude : -122.081651,
    latitudeDelta : 0.01,
    longitudeDelta : 0.01,
    },
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:false,
    annotations : [anno],
    });
```

The result of the above code is, an annotation without label on it,
[Here is the design that i want to achieve](http://www.sohailahmad.me/demo/Location.jpg)

But i want a label on the pin with some text.
Anybody have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am afraid that its impossible to put title on pins.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that its nearly impossible to put title on pins directly. But there is a better way try to create a view programatically add image in that and put label on it.and then convert that view to image and put it as pin image.. this is a sort of hack but will very well work for you. Hope this helps.